# How can I generate hibernate.cfg.xml data from datasource

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, spring-boot, nhibernate-mapping

I have an issue connecting to the datasource.

This error shows when the API runs this function in the API:

```java
UserEntity user = userDAOImpl.getUserById(id);
```

> 2019-08-20 23:30:04.672 ERROR 20424 --- [nio-8080-exec-4]
>   o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for
>   servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
>   [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
>   org.springframework.web.accept.PathExtensionContentNegotiationStrategy$ActivationMediaTypeFactory]
>   with root cause
>
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
>   org.springframework.web.accept.PathExtensionContentNegotiationStrategy$ActivationMediaTypeFactory
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.accept.PathExtensionContentNegotiationStrategy.getMediaTypeForResource(PathExtensionContentNegotiationStrategy.java:159)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.accept.ServletPathExtensionContentNegotiationStrategy.getMediaTypeForResource(ServletPathExtensionContentNegotiationStrategy.java:103)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler.getMediaType(ResourceHttpRequestHandler.java:631)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler.handleRequest(ResourceHttpRequestHandler.java:458)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:51)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]    at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]    at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]    at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]    at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]    at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]    at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]    at
>   java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]

I think the issue is that there is no connection to the datasource.

this is the hibernate.cfg.xml file content

```xml
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
            "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
            "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
    <hibernate-configuration>
      <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.url" />
        <property name="connection.driver_class" />
        <!-- <property name="connection.username"/> -->
        <!-- <property name="connection.password"/> -->

        <!-- DB schema will be updated if needed -->
        <!-- <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property> -->
      </session-factory>
    </hibernate-configuration>
```

**this is the pom**

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

      <groupId>au.edu.rmit.rjeth.events</groupId>
      <artifactId>EventsAPI</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

      <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
      </parent>

      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
          <version>5.4.2</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
          <version>5.4.2</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.json</groupId>
          <artifactId>json</artifactId>
          <version>20190722</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
          <version>5.1.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.orm/hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
          <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
          <version>6.0.0.Alpha2</version>
        </dependency>


      </dependencies>

      <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
      </properties>


    </project>
```

**Datasource**

[image]

**Connection to remote db success**

[image]

**Persistence tab**

[image]

Any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't see dataSource neither transactionManager. I always move hibernate configuration into applicationContext.xml
Below my whole applicationContex.xml file as example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" 
xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="your_package_root_of_beans" />
<context:annotation-config />
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

<!-- dataSource properies -->
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:context/dataSource.properties" />

<!-- hibernate -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${hibernate.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${hibernate.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${hibernate.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${hibernate.password}" />
</bean>
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="your_package_root_of_entities" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true" transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

you need set to variables: `context:component-scan base-package` - package root for your all spring beans and `property name="packagesToScan"` - package root for your all data base entities. This file has rest params in properties file: `dataSource.properties`
example below:

```
hibernate.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
hibernate.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dataBaseName
hibernate.username=postgres
hibernate.password=postgres
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=
```